# Bootstrap 4 form input with icon for validation

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, validation, bootstrap-4, font-awesome

In Bootstrap 3 there were optional icons for each of the validation states. The icon would appear in the right side of the input using the `has-feedback`, `has-success`, `has-danger`, etc... classes.

[image] 
How can I get this same functionality in Bootstrap 4 using the `valid-feedback` or `invalid-feedback` classes?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Bootstrap 4** doesn't include icons (glyphicons are gone), and there are now just 2 validation states (`is-valid` and `is-invalid`) that control display of the `valid-feedback` and `invalid-feedback` text.

With a little extra CSS, you can position an icon inside the input (to the right), and control its' display using `is-valid` or `is-invalid` on the `form-control` input. Use a font lib like fontawesome for the icons. I created a new `feedback-icon` class that you can add to the `valid/invalid-feedback`.

```
.valid-feedback.feedback-icon,
.invalid-feedback.feedback-icon {
    position: absolute;
    width: auto;
    bottom: 10px;
    right: 10px;
    margin-top: 0;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="form-group position-relative">
     <label for="input2">Valid with icon</label>
     <input type="text" class="form-control is-valid" id="input2">
     <div class="valid-feedback feedback-icon">
          <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
     </div>
     <div class="invalid-feedback feedback-icon">
          <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
     </div>
</div>
```

[Demo of input validation icons](https://www.codeply.com/go/w7E80lxnMD)
[Demo with working validation](https://www.codeply.com/go/ufSwK5njxe)

```css
.valid-feedback.feedback-icon,
.invalid-feedback.feedback-icon {
    position: absolute;
    width: auto;
    bottom: 10px;
    right: 10px;
    margin-top: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <div class="form-group position-relative">
     <label for="input2">Valid with icon</label>
     <input type="text" class="form-control is-valid" id="input2">
     <div class="valid-feedback feedback-icon">
          <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
     </div>
     <div class="invalid-feedback feedback-icon">
          <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Notice that the containing `form-group` is `position:relative` using the `position-relative` class.

Answer (score 2):

A simple way to do it with Bootstrap 4 is using stylized [input groups](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/components/input-group/):

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.iconify.design/1/1.0.4/iconify.min.js"></script>

<div class="input-group m-3 w-75 border border-success rounded"> 
  <input type="text" class="form-control border-0" aria-label="Amount (to the nearest dollar)">
  <div class="input-group-append">
    <span class="input-group-text bg-white border-0 text-success"><span class="iconify" data-icon="subway:tick" data-inline="true"></span></span>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="input-group m-3 w-75 border border-danger rounded"> 
  <input type="text" class="form-control border-0" aria-label="Amount (to the nearest dollar)">
  <div class="input-group-append">
    <span class="input-group-text bg-white border-0 text-danger"><span class="iconify" data-icon="subway:multiply-1" data-inline="true"></span></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Obviously you have to include the icons for it to show up:

```html
<script src="https://code.iconify.design/1/1.0.4/iconify.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: For the icons, there is also https://primer.style/octicons/