# classes related with form control classes are not functioning properly in bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

1) `form input` elements' border color does not change to related color as green, orange or red.

2) It does not insert related gif like "ok" or "x" gif into right place of input.

I expected form-control-success or form-control-warning or form-control-danger would work but it did not. Why?

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="form-group">
  <label class="form-control-label text-success" for="inputSuccess2">
            Success
        </label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-success" id="inputSuccess2" aria-describedby="inputSuccess2Status">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="form-control-label text-warning" for="inputWarning2">
            With Warning
        </label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-warning" id="inputWarning2" aria-describedby="inputWarning2Status">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="form-control-label text-danger" for="inputError2">With Error</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-danger" id="inputError2" aria-describedby="inputError2Status">
</div>
```

**EDIT:**

This fixed my issue.[link][1]

[1]: [Bootstrap 4 form input with icon for validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49323175/bootstrap-4-form-input-with-icon-for-validation)**strong text**

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

1) There are no such classes as .form-control-success, .form-control-danger etc specified in Bootstrap 4. You may add them to your own stylesheet, example:

```
.form-control.form-control-success:focus{
   border-color: #28a745;
   box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2rem rgba(40, 167, 69, 0.25);
}
```

2) To insert a gif(s) to the input you will need to further customise your html/css/js. Start here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/input-group/#custom-forms